# Changing variables, maps and lists in another class

Tags: java

I'm supposed to implement twistPlot.

I tried:

1. _friends.getMembers().put("Philip", teacher);
2. _friends.getMembers().remove("Tommy");
3. _pippi.getPets().remove(0);
4. _pippi.getPets().set(1, new Pet("Tiny Uncle"));

For some reason 1, 2, 3 and 2, 3, 4 worked together but not 1, 2, 3, 4.

***Laufzeitfehler***
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:473)
at Story.__twistPlot(**tester**.java:84)
at **tester**.runTests(**tester**.java:111)
at **tester**.main(**tester**.java:107)

```
class Pet {
    String name;

    public Pet(String name) {this.name = name;}
}

class Person {
    private String _name;
    private int _age;
    private List<Pet> _pets;

    public Person(String name, int age, List<Pet> pets) {
        _name = name;
        _age = age;
        _pets = pets;
    }

    public String getName() {return _name;}

    public int getAge() {return _age;}

    public List<Pet> getPets() {return _pets;}
}

class Group {
    private Map<String, Person> _members;

    public Group() {
        _members = new HashMap<String, Person>();
    }

    public void add(Person person) {
        assert person.getAge() < 18 : "No adults allowed";
        _members.put(person.getName(), person);
    }

    public Map<String, Person> getMembers() {return _members;}
}

public class Story {
    private final Person _pippi;
    private final Person _annika;
    private final Person _tommy;

    private final Group _friends;

    public Story() {
        // initialize persons and pets
        List<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<Pet>();
        pets.add(new Pet("Herr Nilsson"));
        pets.add(new Pet("Kleiner Onkel"));
        _pippi = new Person("Pippi", 9, pets);
        _annika = new Person("Annika", 10, new ArrayList<Pet>());
        _tommy = new Person("Tommy", 8, new ArrayList<Pet>());

        // create a circle of friends
        _friends = new Group();
        _friends.add(_pippi);
        _friends.add(_annika);
        _friends.add(_tommy);
        
        twistPlot();
    }

    private void twistPlot() {
        Person teacher = new Person("Martin", 48, new ArrayList<>());
        // 1. add the teacher to the circle of friends with the alias "Philip"
          
        // 2. remove Tommy from the ciorcle of friends
                                                          
        // 3. remove the pet "Herr Nilsson"
                                                          
        // 4. change the name of the pet "Kleiner Onkel" to "Tiny Uncle"
                                                          
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Its not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I want to know how to implement twistPlot().

Comment: Shouldn't a group has a group name?  In your code, the group name is the name of whoever is added last to the group.  In this case, you could get rid of the hashmap and use a list instead.

Comment: I can't change any code that isn't in twistPlot(). I don't know what you mean with group name to be honest and that it is the name of whoever is added last seems weird to me too. I thought that there is only 1 group and it got created with _friends = new Group();.

Comment: `twistPlot()` is an instance method of class `Story` and so it has access to all the fields of that class, including `_friends`, which does not have a method `put` and its `add` method takes a `Person` as an argument. Look at how the other people are created and added in class `Story`.

Comment: Ahhh I see but how am I supposed to remove someone from _friends? The Group class only has an add method and no method that removes persons.

Comment: @Philip730 you have to call `getMembers()` to get the `Map` and then call the remove method on that to remove members. For pets you need to get the member then call that members `getPets()` and then remove from the list.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! 2: _friends.getMembers().remove("Tommy"); 3: _pippi.getPets().remove(0);  4: _pippi.getPets().set(1, new Pet("Tiny Uncle"));, I just don't know how to do 1 yet, I know that I have to change they Key somehow but I'm not sure how.

Comment: You can get the members using `getMembers()` and then use `put()` to add the teacher.

Comment: 1: _friends.getMembers().put("Philip", teacher);. I'm very confused now, 1, 2, 3 worked together and 2, 3, 4 also worked together. But 1, 2, 3, 4 gave me Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1

Comment: Can you add the error message to your question?

Comment: Yea I added it, is it possible to not use an index in the pet methods? But I actually don't understand why it doesn't work with the index. If I change the index in 4 from 1 to 0 it compiles but the test obviously fails then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your step 1, 2, 3 looks correct. There's something wrong with the index in step 4.

Initially, Pippi has two pets: Herr Nilsson and Kleiner Onkel. After `_pippi.getPets().remove(0);`, Pippi has only one pets now (`_pippi.getPets().size() == 1`), and "Kleiner Onkel" becomes the first element of `_pippi.getPets()`, with the new index 0 not 1.

You can add some print statements before step 4 to help you debug:

```java
System.out.println(_pippi.getPets().size());
System.out.println(_pippi.getPets().get(0).name);
```

Therefore, for step 4, you can use:

```java
_pippi.getPets().get(0).name = "Tiny Uncle"; // it doesn't create a new object
// the following statement will create a new Pet object, instead of updating the original pet
// _pippi.getPets().set(0, new Pet("Tiny Uncle"));
```